# expression "x => (DateTime)x[key].Date" for SPListItemCollection

Tags: c#, sharepoint, expression, splistitem

Please help me with building tree expression from this lambda expression

**x => (DateTime)x[key].Date**

x of SPListItem type.
class Expression contains different methods - Expression.Property(...), Expression.MemberInit(...) - **I can't understand how to use this. What methods use in different cases.**

I spent three days to solve this task and no luck.

Upd. Some details: I'm working with SharePoint and I need to sort SPListItemCollection by some fields. In case of DateTime field, it must be sorted only by date. I can't do this with CAML query, so I can use linq.

OrderBy(item => (DateTime)item[fieldName].Date)

works perfectly. But there are can by many parameters for sorting.
I try to create dynamic linq query with help of Expression class. And if my lambda expression was, for example, x=>x.property,it will be simple

**var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(x));

var property1 = typeof(x).GetProperty(property);**

But how I can do this for (item => (DateTime)item[fieldName].Date)?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you provide us with some more context for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: No problem. I've edited my Question. Welcome any futher questions.